# How to change the order of results in an Eloquent collection?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel, eloquent

I have a table which returns the category names. I fetch all the records but the problem is that it has one record which I want to treat differently, "Other Fruits". I want it to be shown last.

For example, when I get the records from database:

```
Category::where('parent_category_id',  $data)->where('is_active', 1)->lists('name', 'id');
```

The collection it returns looks like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [27] => Apple
            [346] => Other Fruits
            [350] => Papaya & Pomegranate
            [377] => Banana
            [438] => Orange & Sweet Lime
        )
)
```

How can I move the "Other Fruits" item to be last?

Comment: Is "Other Store" stored in DB? If yes, how do you identify it?

Comment: sorry its other fruits how will i make sure that other fruits comes last ?

Comment: Ok, but is "Other Fruits" stored in DB?

Comment: @Laerte yes it is stored

Comment: I've reworded the question to make it more obvious what you're looking for Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Hey simply use two rules and get two collection

```
$category = Category::where('parent_category_id',  $data)->where('is_active', 1)->lists('name', 'id');
$other = << use your rule correctly >>
```

then use this collection in your view

```
foreach($category as .....)
foreach($other as ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
$categoriesExceptOtherFruits = Category::where('parent_category_id',  $data)
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->where('id', '<>', $otherFruitsId);

$allCategories = Category::where('parent_category_id',  $data)
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->where('id', $otherFruitsId)
        ->union($categoriesExceptOtherFruits)
        ->lists('name', 'id');
```

If you have few `other` categories, use `like` instead of `<>`.

Another solution is to create `sort` column in your table and just use `orderBy('sort', 'asc')`.

And of course you could reorder collection manually.